# Problem with java socket. Connection refused : connect

Tags: java, sockets

Could anybody please help me? I have this code written, and I have no idea what is happening in the logs. I found something about it but it doesn't work. Could Anybody please help me and tell what is wrong?

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:507)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:287)
    at me.serwer.konfigurujSocket(serwer.java:32)
    at me.serwer.uruchom(serwer.java:24)
    at me.serwer.main(serwer.java:54)
```

```
package me;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class serwer {

    PrintWriter pisarz;
    Socket gniazdo;

    private void konfigurujSocket() {
        try {
            gniazdo = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            pisarz = new PrintWriter(gniazdo.getOutputStream());
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[all code pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QROg.png)

Comment: This code tries to connect to a server running on your local machine listening on port 5000.  Are you running something there?

Comment: Seems more likely that nothing is wrong here and that whatever is supposed to be accepting connections over port 5000 is not working as intended.

Comment: so do I have to change port? I dont run anything on it though

Comment: Change a port for what reason? What are you expecting to happen? Why would connecting to an IP:port that isn't listening return anything at all?

Comment: What are you trying to connect to?  Or, in general, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to run a server on java.io with using java.swing as a GUI. I have a client though, but I cant't seem to do anything because the server doesnt even try listening. On start it just sends me an error. i sent a pic

Comment: The code you show is a client - it is not a server.  It is a client attempting to connect to a server that isn't there.  There are a ton of tutorials available for simple Java socket programming.

Comment: ok, thank you very much

Comment: Please don't post code as image. Also your code in the image differs from what you've included in the text - it is connecting to a different port. And like already said, the problem is that no server is accepting the connection which means that something is wrong with your unknown sever.

Comment: Yeah... I made a mistake. Sorry for bothering You. It works just fine now. I just had to post the picture because even the shorter code was so long, I couldnt post a question. I had to type more about it